# Canonical order for expressions that applied in Sort?

Tags: sorting, expression-form

`Sort[list]` sorts the elements of *list* into **canonical order**.

As an example for sorting expressions: `Sort[{y, x^2, x + y, y^3}]` gives `{x^2, y, y^3, x + y}`

Could anybody please explain what is the canonical order for any expressions that applied in `Sort`?

Comment: I have marked this as a duplicate because I think in essence it is the same as one I asked myself.  If you disagree please let me know.  Unfortunately there doesn't appear to be an official answer.